# implementing friendly urls on an nginx-ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, rewrite

Currently my website's url are like this:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/fx/?category-name=abc` (**category page**)

`https://www.mywebsite.com/fx/?category-name=abc&article-name=xyz` (**article page**)

The index.php file in the folder called **fx** processes the url parameters for the page.

I was hoping, there'll be a way to make it like:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/fx/abc/xyx` for reaching the **article page**, And

`https://www.mywebsite.com/fx/abc` for reaching the **category page**.

by making modifications to the nginx configuration file.

If anyone knows the solution to this problem, please do let me know. I'm using an ubuntu-nginx server.

**I've tried adding these to the server block one at a time. But without any success:**

`rewrite /fx/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\.]+) /fx/index.php?category-name=$1&article-name=$2;`

`rewrite ^/fx/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?category-name=$1 last;`

`location /fx/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /fx/index.php?category-name=$1 last;
}`

Either the address bar show `https://www.mywebsite.com/fx/fx/index.php?category-name=abc` and
a 404 is returned.

Or the address bar shows `https://www.mywebsite.com/fx/abc` and a 404 is returned.

**Edit: This is not a wordpress site.**
(I had done this on a wordpress site I had created before. Tried this as well, after replacing the `wpfolder` with `fx`. But I know that won't work as my fx/index.php file requires a `category-name` argument to display an output.)

```
location /wpfolder/ {
try_files $uri $uri/ /wpfolder/index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Is this a Wordpress site? If so, edit your question to include that

Comment: oh, okay. It's not a wordpress site btw.

Comment: What do the nginx debug logs tell you about how nginx is processing your request?  The first of your rewrite examples looks to be fairly close to the mark, so the debug logs will probably explain what's going wrong.

Comment: Yikes! how do I do that? tried accessing the error log @ /var/log/nginx/error.log as mentioned in the nginx.conf file. But apparently, such a file doesn't exit.